# Spring restTemplate not working for single quotes in URL. Works with postman

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, messageformat

Simple restTemplate exchange used for a GET request.

Header information

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.ALL));
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
headers.add("Authorization",  ************);
```

URL:

```
/api/odata/GetAvailableObjects?fromTime=datetime'2018-02-02T12:00:00'&$format=json&toTime=datetime'2018-02-10T12:00:00'
```

I tried building this URL with either `MessageFormat.format` or `URIBuilder`. 
The single quotes are the problem. So far I tried double-ing them, escaping them
or leaving them as they are.

I enabled some extra logging with : 
logging.level.org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate=DEBUG
This displays the URL.. if I copy that URL and paste it in POSTMAN, I receive results, from spring I receive 400 Bad request.

I suppose it might be some additional encoding to blame.
Any ideas?

Comment: You could try using wireshark to see what actually gets sent.

Answer (score 0):

- The JWT had way to many scopes, the server API decided to throw a 400 without any message and the server logs were not available..
- A flag in `application.properties` that sets the maximum header size.

Comment: Great to see you coming back and answering your own question with the solution you found, but... It's not entirely clear what you're saying - especially for your second point.

Answer (score 0):

```
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(".../api/odata/GetAvailableObjects?fromTime=datetime'2018-02-02T12:00:00'&$format=json&toTime=datetime'2018-02-10T12:00:00'
").build().encode().toUri();
```

and send the uri in rest template
this works for me